# API Class not found using Composer

Tags: composer-php, bigcommerce

I am new to using composer, I have it installed, created composer.json file. Installed bigcommerce api using these instructions: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

When I try to run "use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce" I am getting error class not found.

I am using localhost and my file structure is:

```
testsite
 src-> contains all classes including Client.php
 vendor -> bigcommerce -> api -> the api files, 
 api.php -> my test file trying to connect to api
```

I have not changed any composer files, I have looked into autoloading. As I said before it is first time using composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of Composer here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md Pay attention to the last couple of paragraphs, "Using Composer" and "Autoloading". Did you follow the procedures in your code?